# check_box not working in haml form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, checkbox, haml

I have made a form using form_for tag. I have to make a check_box field with inline label like

[checkbox] Please check this option

I have been trying many options which worked for me before but this time it is not visible even. When I inspect element I get values like this.

```
 = form_for (@subscription ||= Subscription.new),  :html => { :class => "validate formtastic franchise_application", }, url: '/contact_information', :id => "advanced_subscription_form",  :method => "post" do |f|
  %div

    %p
      = f.check_box :is_subscribed, :type => "visible", :value => "1", :checked => "1", :label => "Check here"
```

The output is like this

```
<input name="subscription[is_subscribed]" value="0" type="hidden">
<input value="1" name="subscription[is_subscribed]" id="subscription_is_subscribed" type="checkbox">
```

I have tried many more ways but the checkbox is not visible on screen
              = check_box_tag "subscription[is_subscribed]",0, :is_subscribed, :visible => true
          -#=check_box_tag("is_subscribed")

```
      -#= check_box_tag :subscription_is_subscribed, 1, :name => "subscription[is_subscribed]"
      -#%input{:name => "subscription[is_subscribed]", :type => "visible", :value => "1"}
      -#%input#subscription_is_subscribed{:name => "subscription[is_subscribed]", :type => "checkbox", :hidden => "false", :value => "1"}
      -#= f.check_box(:is_subscribed, "1", "1")
      -#= f.check_box('subscription','is_subscribed')
      -#= f.label :is_subscribed, :required => false, :hidden => false do
      -#  There you go
      -#  = f.check_box :is_subscribed, :required => false, :hidden => false, :value => true
```

The first one has a very fine html source now

```
= check_box_tag "subscription[is_subscribed]",0, :is_subscribed, :visible => true
<input name="subscription[is_subscribed]" id="subscription_is_subscribed" value="0" visible="true" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
```

How is this hidden value showing here. I will be really thankful if someone helps me out here.
I am using Ruby2.2.0 Rails 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use symbols too...

```
= check_box_tag "Accept Terms", :terms
= check_box_tag :terms
```

Answer (score 2):

With `check_box` helper rails for each item with a checked check box you get an extra ghost item with only that attribute, assigned to “0”.

Example

```
= check_box("user", "terms")
# => <input name="user[terms]" type="hidden" value="0" />
# => <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="user_terms" name="user[terms]" value="1" />
```

In your case it is preferable to either use `check_box_tag`

```
= check_box_tag 'terms'
# => <input id="terms" name="terms" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Don't forget the `=` to begin the line...

Comment: update your answer with the view including html source

Comment: I don't understand, do you need remove hidden field and only include `<input name="subscription[is_subscribed]" id="subscription_is_subscribed" value="0" visible="true" checked="checked" type="checkbox">` ?